# Flask-sqlachemy cannot append to and use backref

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

here is my post model:

```
class Post(UserMixin,db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "posts"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key = True)
    posts = db.Column(db.String(500))
    post_author = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("users.id"))
```

here is my User model:

```
 class User(UserMixin,db.Model):
        __tablename__ = "users"
        id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key = True)
        username = db.Column(db.String(60),unique = True, index = True)
        first_name = db.Column(db.String(60),unique = True, index = True)
        last_name = db.Column(db.String(60), index = True)
        password = db.Column(db.String(100))



        user_post = db.relationship("Post",secondary = post , primaryjoin = (post.c.user_id == id), secondaryjoin = (post.c.post_id == Post.id),
        backref = db.backref("authored_post",lazy = "dynamic"),lazy = "dynamic")
```

Now I have a backref on the post model named `authored_post`

this is what I've tried

```
db.session.add(Post(posts = posted, post_author = current_user.id, authored_post = current_user))
```

because basically what I'm trying to do is query all the posts and find out who authored each post through the backref so I can get their `last_name`attribute but doing `authored_post = current_user` will return an error an error that says `User object is not iterable`.

appending to it won't work as well `Post.authored_post.append(current(user))`
it also throws an error. so how do we solve this?

Answer (score 0):

well for the reference of other people who encounter a problem such as this.

I solved it doing this

```
class Post(UserMixin,db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "posts"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key = True)
    posts = db.Column(db.String(500))
    post_author = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("users.id"))
    author = db.relationship("Users")
```

My workaround was simply to add another relationship so when you do

```
db.session.add(Post(posts = posted, post_author = current_user.id, author = current_user))
```

if you query all Post objects like this and get each indivual object:

```
post = [i for i in Post.query.all()]
```

you now have access to the all attributes on the `Users` model!

just do:

```
for i in post:
 print(i.author.first_name,i.author.last_name)
```

Im new to Sqlalchemy and fairly new to python so. I hope  helps some newbies